# Unable to close loop running in thread at application close. tcp/ip

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcplistener

I'm working on one TCP client server application and running the TCP server in loop but when I close the application loop continuously runs and send data to device. 
Here is the scenario:
TCP server runs and listen to client(handheld device) once the device connected as long as there is no data receive from the device server needs to send empty data continuously to device.

Code:

```
private TCPMainListener tcpListener;
private Thread listenThread;
private TcpClient client;
public bool checkFormIsClose { get; set; }
List<Thread> listenThreads;
public void startTcpServer()
{
this.tcpListener = new TCPMainListener(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(tcpport));
this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
this.listenThread.Start();
listenThreads.Add(listenThread);
}

 private void ListenForClients()
        {
            try
            {
                this.tcpListener.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            while (!checkFormIsClose)
            {
                try
                {
                    //blocks until a client has connected to the server
                    client = (TcpClient)this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                    //create a thread to handle communication 
                    //with connected client
                    Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
                    clientThread.Start(client);
                }
                catch
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Client Handle:

```
 private void HandleClientComm(object client)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;

            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            byte[] message = new byte[100];
            int bytesRead;

            while (true)
            {
                bytesRead = 0;

                try
                {
                    //blocks until a client sends a message
                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 40);

                    #region Write to client until message receive
                    int timeout = 0;

                    //send empty byte to device until bytesRead != 0
                    do
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        timeout++;
                        if (timeout == 10)
                        {
                            byte[] b = new byte[] { 0x00 };
                            tcpClient.GetStream().Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                            timeout = 1;
                        }
                    } while (bytesRead == 0);

                    #endregion

                    if (bytesRead != 0)
                    {
                        //message has successfully been received
                        if (BitConverter.ToString(message).Replace("-", "").StartsWith("FF"))
                        {
                            CardProcessing(message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    //a socket error has occured
                    break;
                }
            }

            tcpClient.Close();
        }
```

Now here is my form closing code:
and they are not doing anything at all

```
private void TCPMAINSERVER_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Thread thread in listenThreads)
            {
                checkFormIsClose = true;
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    checkFormIsClose = true;
                    tcpListener.Stop();
                    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Close();
                    GC.SuppressFinalize(thread);
                    thread.Join();
                    thread.Interrupt();
                });
            }
        }

        private void TCPMAINSERVER_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Thread thread in listenThreads)
            {
                checkFormIsClose = false;
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    tcpListener.Stop();
                    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Close();
                    GC.SuppressFinalize(thread);
                    thread.Join();
                    thread.Interrupt();
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your are using `thread.Join()` then `thread.Interrupt()`. it should be way around. First call `thread.interrupt()` and then call `thread.join()`. Do remember that interrupting may or may not actually stop that thread.

Comment: There are many problems with this code. This would benefit from the Code Review Stack Exchange site. Post it there.

Comment: many problem.. could you please point out some, i must sent data continuesly to device otherwise device disconnect itself from system and look for new connection

Comment: You just simply repeated what you already said in the question. This does not help.

Comment: @inquisitive Yeah, `Join` means your thread is going to wait for the other to end, and `Interrupt` doesn't work this way. You'd have to use `Abort`. And that's a bad idea. Dawncode, just use cooperative cancellation - make a `CancellationTokenSource`, and check for the cancellation token to be signalled. When exiting, just call `Cancel`. That said, you still need to close the `TcpClient`, otherwise it's going to block forever on the `Read` call.